# Filtering posts in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a newspaper running on Jekyll. On the home page there’s a bunch of the most recent posts and below them there are posts grouped by various interesting topics. For example:

- Current Headlines (`site.posts[1..9]`)
- Opinions (`site.categories['opinions']`)
- Culture (`site.tags['culture']`)
- …

Now, when rendering the opinions, I don’t want to repeat the stories that are already listed under Current Headlines. Is there an easy way to express that in Liquid, without any Jekyll plugins?

Comment: You could match the post.url with the first 9 posts in an if statement.

Comment: That’s what I thought, but I would love to keep my self-respect, too :–)

Comment: You can also loop through all posts and use an offset on your page loop with an if statement for the tag or category.

Comment: That’s a good idea! Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through all posts with an offset and use an if statement for the category. Offset can be found here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags

```
{% for post in site.posts offset:9 %}
 {% if post.categories contains 'mycat' %}
  {{ post.title }}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Beware with __category__ and __categories__. You'd better use `{% if post.categories contains 'mycat' %}`.